# First letter using RegEx of string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string of full name.
From string to the first letter of every word. Can I get only two letters of first two words from string using only **RegEx**

Expected result is `KC` using only **RegEx**

```js
var str = "Keanu Charles Reeves";
console.log(str);
str = str.match(/\b(\w)/g).join('').substring(0, 2);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you mean you want to get `KeCh` as a result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can do this by only RegEx ? only need `KC`

Comment: You can't unless you use `.replace`. Something like `s.replace(/[^]*?\b(\w)\w*\W+(\w)[^]*|[^]+/, '$1$2')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes this is what i am looking for only **RegEx** Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is best and you should stick to it.

As an *educational-only* alternative, you might use a solution based on a `.replace` method (because all matching methods will require joining multiple matches that you want to avoid, the reason being that you can't match disjoin (non-adjoining) pieces of text into a single group within one match operation):

```
s.replace(/[^]*?\b(\w)\w*\W+(\w)[^]*|[^]+/, '$1$2')
```

It matches the string up to the first word char that is captured into Group 1, matches up to the second word capturing its first word char into Group 2 and then matching all the string to the end, or - upon no match - `[^]+` grabs the whole string, and replaces the whole string with Group 1 and 2 contents.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F5FOah/1)

Comment: Which one is best using RegEx with replace or joining with substring ?

Comment: @JayVaghasiya Multiple matches + joining is very clear/readable/maintainable and is thus preferable.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote `.substring(0,2)` it will take only first 2 letters only just remove it and it will work

```js
var str = "Keanu Charles Reeves";
console.log(str);
str = str.match(/\b(\w)/g).join('');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Only need `KC` and using only **RegEx**

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "Keanu Charles Reeves";
str = str.replace(/(\w).*? (\w).*/, "$1$2");
console.log(str);
```